# Why there is -nan in the output after a few iterations

Tags: c, nan

My code is a simple algorithm for iterating a process. However, after a few iterations, I'm getting `-nan` in the output.

The code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    float n = (a+b-c)*(a+c-b)*(b+c-a)/(4*a*b*c);
    printf("%f ",n);
    float an = (b+c-a)*sqrt((a+b-c)*(a+c-b)/(4*b*c)); 
    float bn = (a+c-b)*sqrt((a+b-c)*(b+c-a)/(4*a*c)); 
    float cn = (a+b-c)*sqrt((a+c-b)*(b+c-a)/(4*a*b));
    a = an;
    b = bn;
    c = cn;
}
```

where `a, b ,c` are floats declared earlier.

In the output, after approx. 20-30 results I'm getting a bunch of `-nan`
How can I fix it? I'm using https://www.onlinegdb.com as a compiler

Comment: What does your debugger say? Maybe you're trying to take the square root of a negative number.

Comment: @tadman [Inferior 1 (process 3118) exited normally]

Comment: Well, where does that crash? What line? What values were used?

Comment: @tadman the initial values for a,b,c were pi, e and ln(2). -nan appears after 50 results.
The results are of order 0.01 - 0.5

Comment: @pmg no negative values in the output
I printed  the new values for each a, b, c and no negatives. 
I guess the problem is they turn to be very small, almost zero

Comment: `4 * almostzero * almostzero * almostzero` yields `0.0`. Try `double` (or `long double`) for possibly a few more loops before it happens again.

Comment: The limit for `float`, on my computer, is approx `2^(-150)` ... for `double` is `2^(-1076)`, for `long double` is `2^(-16447)`

Comment: Last values are equal to `4.53116e-31`. The product is about `9.3e-92`, much less than `2^(-150) = 7e-46`

Answer (score 1):

We can't tell what happened without knowing the initial a,b,c values. But if you put this line instead of your printf you'll quickly get your answer

```
printf("a=%f, b=%f, c=%f, n=%f, ", a, b, c, n);
```

Comment: Thank you!
the initial values for a,b,c were pi, e and ln(2);

It turns out that a,b,c are getting smaller and smaller with each iteration, almost zero.

Answer (score 0):

sqrt() a negative number will produce nan

Comment: As will division by zero :-)